# Wait for a task to end before executing the next code lines

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a problem with my [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) app. The problem is causing a part of my code to download a "channel list" ([JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)), and I need this task to end before executing the next line. I'm trying with dispatch_async, but I haven't have a good result, because the next line is always executed before the download task ends.

```
class RemoteAPI {
    var remoteUrl = ""
    func getData(completionHandler: ((JSON!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> Void {


       //let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.cxntv.com/api/v1/videos/?type=canales&ordering=-id")
       let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: remoteUrl)!
       let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
       let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
       //[mutableRequest addValue:@"x32dsds-223" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X_ROKU_ID"];
       println(request.HTTPBody)

       //request.addValue("xxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "yyy")
       request.addValue("xxx" ,forHTTPHeaderField: "zzz")

       let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

       /* All my code for the httppetition ....*/
```

I call the getgadata function:

```
api.remoteUrl = "example"

    api.getData({data, error -> Void in
        if (data != nil){
            // Fix possible error if no "results" key
            if let results = data["results"].array {
                self.items = results
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.viewUtils.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
            }
            println("Data reloaded")
        } else {
            println("api.getData failed")
            println(error)
        }
    })

/* next line code for execute....

I need these code lines to wait so that the getdata function ends before it can be executed.

*/
```

Comment: You need to place your code that you want to perform after the load is completed into the completion handler of your getData function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion handler is running within a code block, which is async and will run as another thread in the background and the main thread goes right into the code after the block.

```
// Step A.
api.getData({data, error -> Void in
    // Step B.
    if (data != nil){
        // Fix possible error if no "results" key
        if let results = data["results"].array {
            self.items = results
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.viewUtils.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
        }
        println("Data reloaded")
    } else {
        println("api.getData failed")
        println(error)
    }
    // Move your code here.
})
// Step C.
```

In this case, the order of finishing execution could be either A -> B -> C or A -> C -> B, which in your case, is the later. You have to put the code in the block to make sure it follows the correct order.